# WebdriverIO: How to correctly iterate throus elements and log out the getText?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ui-automation, webdriver-io

I want to learn webdriverio.
I try to run this code:

```
client.init().
url('https://www.example.com').
elements('p').then((result) => {
    for (i = 0; i < result.value.length; i++) {
        (client.elementIdText(result.value[i])).
        then((re) => console.log(re))
    }
})
```

but that logs out nothing.

I know i can do it using getText('p'), but just wanna know how to do it using elements('p').

Comment: `elements('p').value.forEach((element) => { return console.log(browser.elementIdText(element.ELEMENT).value)})` Will do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this hint will help you in finding your answer:

```
let totalElements = $$('p').map((result) => {
    return result.getText();
});
console.log(totalElements);
```

Or this option

```
$$('p').forEach(function(result){
    console.log(result.getText());
});
```

Note: [$$ Link](http://webdriver.io/api/utility/$$.html)

And to get it done from your code please do the same `$$`, remove `.value` and change the method to `getText()`. As there is nothing returned because `elementIdText()` will take only selector `ID` as an argument. And `<p>` is not an ID. Refer here for [elmentIdText()](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/elementIdText.html)

```
for(i=0; i<result.length; i++){
  (client.getText(result[i])).
   then((re) => console.log(re))
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `elements('p').value.map((result) => {
    return result.getText();
});`? Otherwise you will get `TypeError: browser.elements(...).map is not a function`.

Comment: Thanks for spotting it. With regards to code that was only a hint to iterate. As the `elements` will return an array of objects and then need to do the `.value` to retrieve that. So replaced the `elements` with `$$` which just returns a normal array